# PHP - Trim doesn't work with white space?

Tags: php, trim

Today, i have very weird problem with trim function.
Here is my code. =and result is 124.
Trim function didn't work with this string ??!

```
$s = '                                                                                  ';
$s = trim($s);
echo strlen($s);exit();
```

Copy & paste doesn't work with this code. 
i don't know what white space is? but trim couldn't strip it :|

you can test this code here:

test:
http:// 70.38.18.62/t.php

You can copy white space and code over there:
http://jsbin.com/ukunuq/1/edit

Comment: outputs 0, as expected for me. I suspect your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have White space character in `$s` or it's a collection of spaces?

Comment: sorry, you can copy & paste this code. this site auto replace to normal white space :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When I look at your t.txt, the $s string is not just spaces. In Hex, it reads a mixture of 20 (space) and C2 and A0 characters. You need to lose those C2 and A0 characters.

They may not display on screen, but they are NOT spaces. Here's my sniff of what's returned

[image: Screen Capture]

Possibly encoding the file in 7-bit ASCII would also reveal the problem.

To clean it up, just select all the text in $s, delete it and then hit space bar to get the right number of spaces. Or use str_repeat(' ', 134) that will do the same. Check the charset of your editor.

Comment: You sir! Are awesome! UpVote! Gives a thought... as to why we need hex editors ;)

Comment: many tks. how can i convert all un-seen characters to white space character with PHP?

Comment: @TomSawyer Just delete the entire line and retype it. Or to do that in PHP use preg_replace() or str_replace(). e.g. $s = str_replace(array("\xC2", "\xA0"), " ", $s);  or preg_replace on a range of hex characters if there are likely to be more.

Comment: @KarmicDice Thanks for the complements!

Comment: @Robbie many tks. i that all un-seen character like white space? i'm using tinymce, and that string is result of it.

Comment: @Robbie tks your your solution. but when i strip all \xA0 , \xC2 character, that's means all unicode character is broken ?!

Comment: $s = str_replace("\xC2\xA0", " ", $s); then to only replace that combination. Will leave other unicode characters in place (unless you have one that ends in A0 follwed by one that starts in C2 - in which case it'll get a lot more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Works here:

```
marc@panic:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $s = '                                                                                  ';
php > $s = trim($s);
php > echo strlen($s);exit();
0
marc@panic:~$
```

PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.2. Not sure where you're getting `124` from. strlen of the original untrimmed $s comes out as 82 for me.

Comment: you can test my code here. can't copy & paste these white space

http:// 70.38.18.62/t.php
code:
http:// 70.38.18.62/t.txt

Comment: I cut&paste exactly what you have above. What you have in those two urls is no different.

Comment: you can copy php code over there http://jsbin.com/ukunuq/1/edit . 100% didn't work with TRIM

Comment: t.php just has the OUTPUT of your script. there's nothing to run, since it's just the results of your script. t.txt has only 82 chars in your string, no matter how you squint at it.

Comment: Ok, I cut&paste your jsbin link. Still get 0 as the results, and 82 for the length of the original $s. Whatever the problem is, it's NOT with standard PHP, so check that your install is correct, and that whatever YOUR source code file has, that's it really whitespace, and not some funky unicode chars that masquerade as spaces.

Comment: i'm using CODA . copy code from jsbin.com (HTML part). return 124 as i said.

Answer (score 0):

Due to [PHP DOCS](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) `trim();` function with no second paramenter escapes

```
" " (ASCII 32 (0x20)), an ordinary space.
"\t" (ASCII 9 (0x09)), a tab.
"\n" (ASCII 10 (0x0A)), a new line (line feed).
"\r" (ASCII 13 (0x0D)), a carriage return.
"\0" (ASCII 0 (0x00)), the NUL-byte.
"\x0B" (ASCII 11 (0x0B)), a vertical tab.
```

So yo have only one of this characters in `$s` variable. Others are not visible but are not one from the list.